# What happens when we create a parameterized constructor with a pointer arguement?

Tags: c++

For example, can you explain what would happen in the following code?

```
class Vector{
  int v[3];
  Vector(int *x);//parameterized constructor created
};

Vector::Vector(int *x)//definition of the parameterized constructor
{
  for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    v[i]=x[i];//what happens here?? why did we take pointer as arguement?
}
```

From my understanding, by putting `v[i]=x[i]` we created a new array in which all elements of `v` are now in `x`. Why did this require a pointer argument? Couldn't it have been done with a reference `&`?

Comment: "all elements of v are now in x" - ???

Comment: Whatever the reasons, it is very unsafe code. The constructor will accept an `int` array of any size, or a pointer to a single `int`. That is not a good thing. You could mitigate this problem by making the parameter a reference to an array of 3 ints, or using `std::array<int, 3>` instead.

Comment: You've copied the data which is pointed to by `x`, into the array `v`. There is no need to use a reference. If your data `x` was in the form of a STL container, e.g. a `std::vector`, then a reference would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes back to older style C habits, when you can use a pointer as an array, by "indexing" it's elements.

Taken from: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Pointers_and_arrays

- A variable declared as an array of some type acts as a pointer to that type. When used by itself, it points to the first element of the array.
- A pointer can be indexed like an array name.

However, a few notes:

> `v[i]=x[i]` we created a new array

No, you did not create a new array here, the array was already created when the body of the constructor got executed. What happens here is that TO the value `v[i]` we will assign the value of: `*(x + i)` ie. the `i`th. element from the address `x` points to. Unless you know how `x` was created and initialized this is pretty dangerous code. Just imagine you can call this method with the address of a single `int`. I suppose, `size` is 3 or less, otherwise this code has serious security issues.

You always should check for null pointers, before trying to access the value they point to.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the array by reference if you know the size of `x` at compile time:

```
Vector(int (&x)[3]);
```

If you don't know the size at compile time then what you're doing goes from being unsafe code, to blatantly wrong code.

Another option is to use `std::array` if you know the size at compile time, and `std::vector` if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a bit to previous answers, the indexing operator `[]` actually dereferences a pointer and shifts it by index*sizeof(type) at the same time. The same relates to declaration of an array. Say, if you declare `int a[1];` this means that `a` is now a pointer to int, i.e. `int*`. So if you wanted to pass it to a function as an argument, you would need to specify its type as `int*`.